# How to get average volume level of a mp3 file

Tags: audio, mp3

I have to normalize volume level of some speech recording. But every recording seems to be at difference volume level. Is there any tool that can get some statistics of volume level? So I know how much dB I have to increase/decrease during normalization. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try **[Mp3Gain](http://mp3gain.sourceforge.net/)** which is a free tool. The info on the homepage says:

> MP3Gain does not just do peak
>   normalization, as many normalizers do.
>   Instead, it does some statistical
>   analysis to determine how loud the
>   file actually *sounds* to the human ear.

So it should give you the statistics you want.

Comment: When using Mp3Gain, be sure to use "Album analysis" and "Album gain" to get the results you want.

Comment: It doesn't sound like the asker wants to use "Album" mode. It sounds like he wants all the recordings to end up a similar volume.  Album mode would maintain the relative loudness between each recording -- all the recordings together would average out to a certain volume level, but the quieter recordings would stay quieter relative to the louder recordings.  Track mode sounds like the best bet for this situation.

Comment: I would still use Album mode though. I used Mp3Gain on my whole collection actually, hehe. Much better to listen to music afterwards!